# Can not install any printer

Tags: printing

I'm a new user of Ubuntu 16.04. My problem is that I can't install any printer because the button "Add" at the "Printer -localhost" window of "System Settings" is inactive. My printer is a Lexmark E350d laser printer.Thank you in advance!

Comment: Paste this `http://127.0.0.1:631/admin` into your browser and select administration and click add printer, and see if your printer can be seen

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using as I don't see drivers for the anything above `12.04`, see: http://support.lexmark.com/index?locale=EN&page=product&userlocale=EN_US&productCode=LEXMARK_E350D&focusedTab=DOWNLOADS#1

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 - But I can't add any printer "Add" button is inactive

Comment: How can I do this? I can't access this location

Comment: Yes, I did it  but it says that is "unable to connect"

Comment: Please try it without the admin part!

Comment: (I 've got a message to avoid extended discussions in comments). Anyway, I've already tried it without "admin" , it didn't help. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but try navigate to `http://localhost:631/` on a web browser, as this is the cups utility for your printing system. You can define new settings/add printer on this page.

To add printer, go to `http://localhost:631/admin`, click <kbd>Add Printer</kbd> button on **Printers** section.

However, if the page fail to load or return with error, it could be the cups service is not running. In that case, run:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/cups start
```